# Как в react router v4 сделать switch с вложенными компонентами?

Tags: react-router

Всем доброго времени суток!

Прохожу [этот](https://maxfarseer.gitbooks.io/react-router-course-ru/content/browserhistory_vs_hashhistory.html) туториал.
Там есть такой код:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
<Route path='/' component={App}>
  <IndexRoute component={Home} />
  <Route path='admin' component={Admin} />
  <Route path='genre' component={Genre} />
</Route>
<Route path='*' component={NotFound} />
```

Пытаюсь переписать его на react router v4.

Получается как-то так:

```
<BrowserRouter>
<Switch>
  <App>
    <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
    <Route path='/admin' component={Admin} />
    <Route path='/genre' component={Genre} />
  </App>
  <Route component={NotFound} />
</Switch>
```

В этом варианте не отображается NotFound.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch перебирает children и стопорит перебор, когда нужный роут найден. У вас в Switch две ноды... В общем нужно убрать обёртку App. Если вам нужно обернуть часть страниц в App, то можно сделать так:

```
// high order component
// генерирует компонент, который оборачивает исходный в App
const withAppLayout = Component => props => <App><Component {...props} /></App>

<Switch>
  <Route exact path='/' component={withAppLayout(Home)} />
  <Route path='/admin' component={withAppLayout(Admin)} />
  ...
</Switch>
```

Можно создать кастомный Route:

```
const AppRoute = ({ component, ...props }) => (
  <Route {...props} component={withAppLayout(component)} />
);

<Switch>
  <AppRoute exact path='/' component={Home} />
  <AppRoute path='/admin' component={Admin} />
  ...
</Switch>
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам ОГРОМНОЕ за такой подробный ответ!
Это именно то, что нужно!

Answer (score 0):

у меня получилось вот что

```
const LoginLayout = ({ ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <img src={logo} className="logo" alt="logo" />

      <div className="login-container">
        <div className="left-side">
          <ToastContainer className="toaster" />
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/login/reset" component={ResetPassword} />
            <Route path="/login/password_reset" component={NewPassword} />
            <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default ({ childProps }) => (
  <Switch>
    <LoginLayout path="/login" component={LoginLayout} />
    <PrivateRoute path="/" exact name="Home" component={DefaultLayout} />
  </Switch>
);
```

роутинг работает, но кажется что неправильный подход. не могли бы специалисты поправить?